# Не удалось создать таблицу: (1046) No database selected

Tags: php, веб-программирование

пытаюсь создать таблицу. но выводит ошибку:
Не удалось создать таблицу: (1046) No database selected

```
   $mysqli = new mysqli("laravel", "root", "");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    else {
    echo "подключено";
    }
    if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") ||
    !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(adv INT)") ||
    !$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(adv) VALUES ($sp)")) {
    echo "Не удалось создать таблицу: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте строку создания соединения. Вы указали название бд, как я понял, вместо адреса соединения

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

P.S. Но вообще, если вы работаете с laravel, то в нем есть встроенный инструмент для создания соединений с базой. Для этого вы можете указать данные для базы данных в .env файле и работать с базой данных через eloquent. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/database)

Comment: да, вы правы, заметил сразу, но почему-то не удалился пост, но все равно спасибо:)

Comment: с laravel не работаю, просто название не мог придумать :D